# BASH SCRIPT : how to add pre defined parameter value for "amplify add api ''

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

Here I want to know how to get pre-defined parameters for **amplify add api** command in this bash script. Actually, I have to write an automation script to create amplify, Rest API, and lambda function using a bash script.

In below code as you can see for
**AMPLIFY="{

"projectName":"AmplifyNeelDemo",

"envName":"dev",

"defaultEditor":"code"

}"**

pre-defined params are projectName, envName, defaultEditor so like that
I want to get this kind of params for **amplify add api** for the automation script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
IFS='|'
REACTCONFIG="{\
\"SourceDir\":\"src\",\
\"DistributionDir\":\"build\",\
\"BuildCommand\":\"npm run-script build\",\
\"StartCommand\":\"npm run-script start\"\
}"
AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG="{\
\"configLevel\":\"project\",\
\"useProfile\":false,\
\"profileName\":\"default\",\
\"accessKeyId\":\"accesskey\",\
\"secretAccessKey\":\"secaccesskey\",\
\"region\":\"us-east-1\"\
}"
AMPLIFY="{\
\"projectName\":\"AmplifyNeelDemo\",\
\"envName\":\"dev\",\
\"defaultEditor\":\"code\"\
}"
FRONTEND="{\
\"frontend\":\"javascript\",\
\"framework\":\"react\",\
\"config\":$REACTCONFIG\
}"
API="{\
\"service\":\"REST\",\
\"name\":\"myapi\",\
\"path\":\"/hello\",\
\"lambdaFunction\":$LAMBDA_FUN\
}"
LAMBDA_FUN="{\
\"name\":\"Hello-World\",\
\"runtime\":\"NodeJS\",\
\"template\":\"Hello World\"\
}"

PROVIDERS="{\
\"awscloudformation\":$AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG\
}"

amplify init \
--amplify $AMPLIFY \
--frontend $FRONTEND \
--providers $PROVIDERS \
--yes

amplify add api \
--api $API \
--lambda_function $LAMBDA_FUN \
--no

amplify push -y

amplify add hosting

amplify publish -y
```